# how to get return output like[karthi,keyan,ram]`

Tags: java, spring-boot

ok,i am using java spring boot and i wand my return output as array.

i tried lot but i could not find the solution.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

```
public List<Student> findByAge(String age){


    return studentRepository.abc(age);
}
```

```
@GetMapping(value = "info/{age}")
public List<Student> findByAge(@PathVariable(value = "age") String age) {
}
```

```
@Query(value = "{'age':{$gte:?0}}",fields = "{'name':1}")
List<Student> abc(String age);
}
```

Comment: i want code to be write to get what i need

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.